# Scala related trait, abstract types

Tags: scala, traits, subtype, abstract-type

I have 2 related traits.  Dao will be used be a class and DaoHelper will be used by Dao's companion object.  I would like trait Dao to be able use functions defined in DaoHelper, the only way I could figure out how to do this is to define the companion trait as a val. However somehow companion expects its type to be D.this.T which I thought I has defined as a subtype of Doa.  I am confused here.  My apologies for the newb question, I come from a dynamic language background.

/test2.scala:14: overriding value companion in trait Dao of type Test.DaoHelper[D.this.T];
[error]  value companion has incompatible type
[error]     val companion = D

```
object Test extends App {

  trait Dao {
    type T <: Dao
    val companion: DaoHelper[T]
    def getHelpfulData = companion.help
  }

  trait DaoHelper[Dao] {
    val help = "Some helpful data"
  }

  class D extends Dao {
    val companion = D
  }

  object D extends DaoHelper[D]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`companion` has type DaoHelper[T], but T isn't specified anywhere in D, so how would the compiler know it is supposed to be D in class D? You can fix it by overriding it in D.

```
class D extends Dao {
  type T = D
  val companion = D
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. Actually I wanted to avoid having to explicitly declare the type in the concrete class. After mucking around, the magically `'_'`: `val companion: DaoHelper[_ <: Dao]`.  I should have known.  I guess this is saying, accept any type for the DaoHelper type constructor that has a supertype of Dao???  Obviously I got rid of the T altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do with `class D`, but you are getting this error because you are assigning `D` to `companion` in `class D`, but `companion` has type `DaoHelper[T]` as defined in `Dao`.  Since `D` has type `Dao` and `Dao` is not a subtype of `DaoHelper[T]`, this will not work.

Comment: `D` (the object) does not have type `Dao`, it extends `DaoHelper[D]`.

Comment: I think that I am assigning object D to val companion.  object D is a subtype of DaoHelper[D] and class D is a subtype of Dao.

Comment: Maybe I can rephrase my requirements because I agree that I did not explain them very well. I have 2 traits, 1 will be used for a class and one will be used by an object.  The object will be the companion object for the class.  I would like to be able to refer to the companion object in the class however not explicitly ( Not Classname.function() ).  It seems like setting a val in the trait that the class extends from, that corresponds to the companion object, seemed like the easiest way.  However I am not sure what type to give that val.